# DocuSign embedded signing link redirected to an envelope setup page

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to use Embedded Signing feature of DocuSign on the Salesforce platform. I followed the Java version from the documentation (http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning).

I was successfully able to integrate and get the `urlToken`. But when I copy paste the `urlToken` in a new browser window, it is redirecting me to `https://demo.docusign.net/Member/EnvelopeSetupTab.aspx?ti=2342`.

Can somebody please explain this behavior? Is there any setting for envelope that I missed?

Also I am testing this on the Demo account, so is that causing this behavior? I would really appreciate any kind of help on this.

Comment: Why yes -- I know nothing, but it's easy to imagine the API will at least prevent you from poking your token into a new browser window that is outside the session...

Comment: @Samndoli Thank you the reply. Well I am page referencing in the code to open this URL on the click of a button from a visual force page. And as such the session is not timing out, because after a couple of minutes, I actually get a message saying that the session has timed out. Is there any other way I can test this out which you may know of?

Comment: No, sorry I don't.   Have you tried `docusign embedded` in the Stack Overflow search bar?  There are quite a few posts with accepted answers.

Comment: Yes, I did go through some of them, and found no viable solution.

Comment: DocuSign embedding URL tokens have some security built into them, they are valid only for one-time use and expire after 5 mins of use.  Were you violating any of these conditions when testing in the new browser?

Comment: It may help to know a bit about the recipient.  Are they set as a signer?  Are they the same person (email/name) as the sending user?  Finally, are you creating the envelope in a Sent state or Draft state?  If it is a draft, you might be triggering an embedded tagging window.

Comment: @JeffKyllo The recepient and sender email addresses are different, even though the person is the same.I am creating the envelope in Sent state.

Comment: @Ergin Actually the session does timeout once I use this URL, as they are only meant for a one time use. And no, I am not violating the 5 minute limit for each session.

Comment: Well in that case I think we need more specific info to help debug, can you post the actual JSON request body that you are sending out (minus the document bytes if it's a private doc)?  Or better yet the code that creates the request in question?